# User roles are zero after login in MVC6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I am using the default site template that comes in visual studio 2015. I have added some roles and assigned roles to the user. When a used signs in, the roles are zero. What do I need to do to get the roles working?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var signInStatus = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

                switch (signInStatus)
                {
                    case SignInStatus.Success:

                        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();


                        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                    case SignInStatus.Failure:
                    default:
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                        return View(model);
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: can you add the code that adds the user in the role ?

Comment: I think it was the same issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28356740/1593334

Comment: Add the code that adds the user in the role

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it looks like you're missing any check for a role.

I was having this similar problem and after digging into the code I noticed that `GetCurrentUserAsync()` was not returning a valid user object and was intact returning a null object. `Context.User.GetUserId()` is the problem and isn't returning a user id to pass on to the UserManager.

Until this is resolved I'm using the following:

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    if (await UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, Roles.Admin))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
    }

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

While this isn't ideal it does work

Answer (score 0):

This works for me...does not redirect correct for Invalid username or password 4 me yet...will check...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                return View("Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

this is for MVC 6, (VS 2015 RC)...u can find it all here : https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc

Comment: O yes..remeber to set your basic auth to true in the aplicationhost.config (for your IISExpress) for FBA