# How to turn on Roles in Asp.net Identity 3.0 and MVC 6?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-3

I am not sure if I am missing something here. By Default `User.IsInRole()` does not work even if user DOES HAVE some roles.

I don't have my own implementation of role stores. I am assuming that the default ones should work. Is there something special that I need to do in the `Startup.cs` to get the roles working? I'm using mvc 6 beta 2 default template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User.IsInRole()` does not work if I add a role like this:

`await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");`

But it does work if I do this:

`await UserManager.AddClaimAsync(user, claim: new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role.ToString(), "Admin"));`

Comment: I assume you also are awaiting the AddToRoleAsync call?

Comment: What is the result of AddToRoleAsync call ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Asp.NET Identity with the latest ASP.NET 5 stuff. I'm using the same (currently using RC1). I had a similar issue, and after some digging I found a solution by using `SignInManager`'s `RefreshSignInAsync()` method.

Note that to get a hold of an instance of `UserManager` and `SignInManager` I use dependency injection, so the constructor for my controller looks like this:

```
public MyController(
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
    SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    _signInManager = signInManager;
}
```

My requirement was that if a particular controller method was accessed by an authenticated user, then a role would be added to that user if the user didn't already have that role, and it needed to take effect immediately. (Subsequent calls to `User.IsInRole("TheRole")` in controllers and views need return true without the user having to log out and back in).

Here's the action:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProfile()
    {
        if (User == null || User.Identity == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RegisterOrSignIn", "Account");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!User.IsInRole("TheRole"))
            {
                ApplicationUser applicationUser =
                    await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.GetUserId());
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(applicationUser, "TheRole");
                await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(applicationUser);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Note you need

```
using System.Security.Claims;
```

for the `GetUserId()` extension method.

So the big things that I learned was to use `UserManager`'s `AddToRoleAsync` and `SignInManager`'s `RefreshSignInAsync`. The first adds a row to the AspNetUserRoles table. The second refreshes the cookie that, with the next request from the browser, will show that the user is in the role.

As an aside, I added a method called `EnsureRoles()` to Startup.cs. I call it right after the call to `app.UseIdentity()` in `Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)`. So, here's a snipit from `Configure()`:

```
    ...

    // Add cookie-based authentication to the request pipeline.
    app.UseIdentity();

#pragma warning disable CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed
    // Ensure roles are in DB - OK not to await this for now
    EnsureRoles(app, loggerFactory);
#pragma warning restore CS4014 // Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed

    ...
```

and here is `EnsureRoles()`:

```
private async Task EnsureRoles(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Startup>();
    RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

    string[] roleNames = { "TheRole", "AnotherRole" };

    foreach (string roleName in roleNames)
    {
        bool roleExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(roleName);
        if (!roleExists)
        {
            logger.LogInformation(String.Format("!roleExists for roleName {0}", roleName));
            IdentityRole identityRole = new IdentityRole(roleName);
            IdentityResult identityResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole);
            if (!identityResult.Succeeded)
            {
                logger.LogCritical(
                    String.Format(
                        "!identityResult.Succeeded after 
                         roleManager.CreateAsync(identityRole) for 
                         identityRole with roleName {0}",
                        roleName));
                foreach (var error in identityResult.Errors)
                {
                    logger.LogCritical(
                        String.Format(
                            "identityResult.Error.Description: {0}", 
                            error.Description));
                    logger.LogCritical(
                        String.Format(
                            "identityResult.Error.Code: {0}", 
                         error.Code));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```